# Extending jQuery event object before on handler gets triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I can't find a solution for this, so I hope someone here can help me.
I'm trying to extend the jQuery event object before the event gets triggered on the element.

E.g.

```
anyElem.on("mouseenter", function (e) {}
```

`e` in this case is the default jQuery event object. But before the event gets triggered I want to extend that object somehow with some properties. Would be cool to do this in a custom jQuery plugin.

I think a way could be adding an `eventlistener` on capture in vanilla js and modify that event object, but im not sure about this and it would be cool to access the property directly on the jQuery event object and **not** using the `originalEvent` property

```
e.originalEvent.myProperty
```

Comment: Why don't you use `e.preventDefault();`, and do whatever you want with it?

Comment: Well thats not what I want. I want to add properties to that event object before the on event handler function gets called. Doesnt matter which element the (in this case) 'mouseenter'-event is bound to.

Comment: Ah I see. Could `Object.defineProperty();` be a clue then? [check it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: Uhm yes, but I would have to call that on the jQuery event object before the event handler gets called, so I can modify the event object before it gets passed to the handler. Like if there would be a jQuery method like `anyElem.beforeOn('mouseenter', function(e){Object.defineProperty(...)})` this would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this it might help [jQuery Event Extensions](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/)

Comment: Awesome! fixHooks filter function is exactly the thing i need :)!